# What happens to members of a stack-allocated class put down with placement new on scope end?

Tags: c++11, stdvector, member, placement-new, alloca

I have this (compiling) code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Base {
    std::vector<Base*> handles_;

public:
    Base(Base* handle) : handles_( {handle} ) { };
};

class A : public Base {
    using Base::Base;
};

class B : public Base  {
    using Base::Base;
};

int main()
{
    A* addr_of_A = (A*)alloca(sizeof(A));
    B* addr_of_B = (B*)alloca(sizeof(B));

    new (addr_of_A) A(addr_of_B);
    new (addr_of_B) B(addr_of_A);
}
```

Are the vectors inside A and B taken care of by the compiler? Afaik to destroy an object allocated like A and B, I would have to call the destructor explicitely. I'm not doing that here and I'm wondering if the destructor is still called for the member vectors of A and B when scope ends. This is of course necessary as they manage heap ressources.

Comment: `I'm wondering if the destructor is still called for the member vectors of A and B when scope ends.` No.

Comment: @tkausl: So how should I go about it? Define a custom destructor that is manually called which destroys the member vector?

Comment: You don't need a custom one, just call the one generated by the compiler.

Comment: @datenwolf: I think you're missing the point. I need the addresses of each object A and B before they are created so I can pass them to each objects constructor. I would not indulge in such "self-flagellation" otherwise :)

Comment: @datenwolf: No I mean the pointer to the OTHER object

Comment: @glades: I see. Why'd you want to introduce a circular dependency in that way? I don't know. Everything about this just just feels so wrong.

Comment: @datenwolf: Yes the circular dependency is exactly what I need. I'm implementing a state machine where sometimes states can be "adjacent" to other states. So they need to know each others address so I can polymorphically switch contexts.

Comment: @glades: Well, if your use case is a couple of mutually dependent instances which are born and die together, just put them into a containing struct. In that struct's constructor you can grab the addresses of each member.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contain them into an encompassing struct like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Base {
    std::vector<Base*> handles_;

public:
    Base(Base* handle) : handles_( {handle} ) { };
};

class A : public Base {
    using Base::Base;
};

class B : public Base  {
    using Base::Base;
};

int main()
{
    struct C {
        A a;
        B b;
        C() : a(&b), b(&a) {}
    } c;
}
```

Comment: That must be the greatest idea since sliced bread, thank you! It's much cleaner this way but I didn't even think of it :)